# Why are geoalgorithms missing from QGIS processing toolbox (GRASS & SAGA)

Tags: qgis, toolbox, grass-7.2

I am wanting to calculate albedo from a Landsat 8 set of bands. When I use GRASS' Processing toolbox i.albedo, within QGIS, the option for landsat 8 is not avaialbe, however if I use GRASS separately it is (See photos below) Also, notice that the newest version of GRASS has included albedo calculation for Landsat 8 from the latest manual.
[image] 
[image]

Comment: See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223824/activating-grass-utilities-in-qgis-processing-toolbox-via-text-descriptors